# Monotouch application not working when published to iPhone

Tags: c#, iphone, ios5, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm in a bit of a pickle here. I have completely developed my application in Monotouch and tested it on the simulator. Everything works as it is suppose to. When I publish the app to my iPhone in debug or release, it uploads the application to the device yet I am greeted with the following stack trace and when I try to launch the application on the device, the startup Image is displayed and then it just quits unexpectedly. Im sorry but this is all the info I have on this and I hope someone can help me.

Stack Trace:

```
Please ensure your device is connected...
Connected to: JJ iPhone
2012-08-27 19:48:24.841 mtouch[1070:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x9769eb67 __raiseError + 231
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x9a622149 objc_exception_throw + 155
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x975a7bc6 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 150
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x975a7b20 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
    4   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x03cdfdaf __DTDKDeviceSupportSearchPathURLs_block_invoke_0 + 451
    5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x962dca6f dispatch_once_f + 50
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x962dca38 dispatch_once + 31
    7   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x03cdfe95 DTDKDeviceSupportURLs + 104
    8   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x03ce0348 __DTDKMappedDeveloperDiskImageURLs_block_invoke_0 + 23
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x962dca6f dispatch_once_f + 50
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x962dca38 dispatch_once + 31
    11  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x03ce11be __72+[DTDKDeviceSupportFiles _inexactDeveloperDiskImageForVersion:andBuild:]_block_invoke_0141 + 125
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x962db126 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 30
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x962db5b6 dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 87
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x962db70c dispatch_sync + 45
    15  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x03ce0fea +[DTDKDeviceSupportFiles _inexactDeveloperDiskImageForVersion:andBuild:] + 228
    16  DTDeviceKitBase                     0x03ce0ef8 +[DTDKDeviceSupportFiles idealDeveloperDiskImageForVersion:andBuild:allowFallback:] + 54
    17  ???                                 0x02797d2c 0x0 + 41516332
    18  ???                                 0x02796d74 0x0 + 41512308
    19  ???                                 0x02796764 0x0 + 41510756
    20  ???                                 0x02796260 0x0 + 41509472
    21  ???                                 0x02796218 0x0 + 41509400
    22  ???                                 0x02795230 0x0 + 41505328
    23  ???                                 0x02795037 0x0 + 41504823
    24  ???                                 0x027d6048 0x0 + 41771080
    25  MobileDevice                        0x03b58bcf _AMDDeviceAttachedCallbackv3 + 163
    26  MobileDevice                        0x03b0e22d USBMuxIntCFSocketCallback + 1633
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x975b7edb __CFSocketPerformV0 + 1163
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x9756b3df __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x9756ad96 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 246
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x97594c68 __CFRunLoopRun + 1112
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x9759447c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 332
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x975a51a1 CFRunLoopRun + 129
    33  ???                                 0x02794f4c 0x0 + 41504588
    34  ???                                 0x02794f14 0x0 + 41504532
    35  ???                                 0x02755c98 0x0 + 41245848
    36  ???                                 0x02755b98 0x0 + 41245592
    37  ???                                 0x0218cf60 0x0 + 35180384
    38  ???                                 0x02186db0 0x0 + 35155376
    39  ???                                 0x02189216 0x0 + 35164694
    40  mtouch                              0x0001caef WriteZStream + 102623
    41  mtouch                              0x0022f61a WriteZStream + 2276362
    42  mtouch                              0x0023213c WriteZStream + 2287404
    43  mtouch                              0x002313a1 WriteZStream + 2283921
    44  mtouch                              0x000b878f WriteZStream + 740735
    45  mtouch                              0x000b89e0 WriteZStream + 741328
    46  mtouch                              0x000bae4f WriteZStream + 750655
    47  mtouch                              0x00002eb3 mtouch + 7859
    48  mtouch                              0x00002755 mtouch + 5973
    49  ???                                 0x0000000b 0x0 + 11
)
```

I know I might sound idiotic now but I am new to iPhone and Monotouch development and have no idea how to read or interpret this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stack traces with mtouch are particularly difficult. From my experience, it's much easier to step through the code and find the section that throws the error.

Comment: Hi @Ingenu. You see that's the problem. This only happens when publishing to the device. Even when stepping through the code in debug mode when published to the device, I do not get to the first breakpoint. It happens before that.

Comment: I find that the simulator is unreliable to use while developing. This sort of problem almost always arises when finally testing on a real device. My advise is you should only develop/test on real iphones/ipads/or ipod touhces.

Answer (score 2):

That's likely a version mismatch between components. Please fill a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) and include:

- the version of MonoTouch;
- the version of MonoDevelop;
- the version of OSX;
- the version of Xcode;
- the type (which iPhone) and version of the iOS device;
- the complete build log (add "-v -v -v" to your project's **Additional mtouch arguments**) copy/pasted from MonoDevelop's **Build Output** (from the **Error List** pad).

The first four items you can get from within MonoDevelop. From the **MonoDevelop** menu, select the **About MonoDevelop** item, then the **Version Information** tab and copy/paste that data into the bug report.